# In Facebook, anyway to post to a group and just have those in that group see the post?

Tags: facebook

I'm in a fb group that requires approval to join, but it is public.  I want to post to that group without having all my other friends see my post.  I'm not trying to hide my post, but my friends have told me that they are just not interested in all my GM Volt questions (though they are interested in my other stuff).

I've looked at privacy and it's not obvious to me how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If the group is public the group is public. Only an admin can change this.

Comment: So without creating another account, there is no way to segregate my posts so all my friends do not see it?

Comment: Exactly. A new account for GW Volt questions without these uninterested friends would mean that they would never see such posts. An unsatisfactory solution however.